# Site collection level layout page not working

Tags: sharepoint-server, master-page, site-collection, page-layout, popup

I had created one site collection under web application using same site template.
I have two master pages one for admin level one for read level permission users.

Everything was working fine with top level site.But in site collection all the popups are not opening. I see a "File not found error".

I checked with logfile using this id.I found below errors.

```
Application error when access /_layouts/15/Test.aspx, 
Error=The file /_catalogs/masterpage/User.master does not exist.
```

and

```
Claims Windows Sign-In: Sending 401 for request 'url of the site' because the user is not authenticated and resource requires authentication.
```

[image]

How to resolve this issue ? can you please someone help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I sounds from your question that you have two sitecollections and the Test.aspx page i working in one but not the other.

Remember that the _catalogs url always refers to a folder on the site so you need to copy the master page to all site collections and refer to it from the root of the sitecollection.

The _layouts directory on the other hand is global. Consider storing the master page in the _layouts directory instead if that works for you.

Comment: how to add masterpage to sitecollections.In site settings-->Master pages-->my custom master pages are present.But i checked in sharepoint designer and  SharePoint manager masterpages folders are not there.

Comment: @Elina have you enabled Publishing feature on site and web? Remember to mark as answer.